# Why the first element of the return value of the jQuery empty() function is the element itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw a code as bellow in a javascript function:

```
A.empty()[0].options.add(new Option('', ''));
```

and A is a dom select element. It seems `A.empty()[0]` is refering to the same select element. This means that empty returns an array whose first element is the dom object itself (i.e, A here).

Can somebody explain this behavior or link me somewhere I can read about this behaviour? (Or I completely misunderstood this code!?)

update: looking at the API documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) does say the return value is a jQuery. Is this the expected behavior of the jQuery functions that their return value's first element is always the element the function is called upon (given the return value is of type jQuery)?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: A.empty() will return data-set(Like array but not array) so 0th element you are taking

Comment: jQuery tends to always return the selected element or elements, so you can chain command, exactly as the example you've given.  In the example you've given I would guess that `A` is a jQuery object (of a DOM select element), and you then use `[0]` to get the DOM element itself.

Comment: It would appear your `A` variable holds a jQuery object. If so your mish-mash of JS/jQuery can be translated to `A.empty().first().append('<option></option>');`

Comment: `looking at the API documentation here does not provide the answer!` Yes it does, top right: `Returns jQuery`

Comment: @Rory, right. it provides certain insight. it says return value is jQuery. thx

Comment: @Archer. Can I always get the element itself after a jQuery function call, by looking at the first element of its return value, if the return value type is  jQuery?

Comment: Generally yes, but don't take anything for granted.  If you want to be 100% sure use `$("#elementId")[0]` instead of a function return

Comment: @qartal if you assume that a jQuery selector will always find exactly 1 element then you're bound to have a bad time at some point down the line. $(selector).length tells you how many elements you have and you can do $(selector)[index] to get the DOM object for each one. The jQuery object may be empty though so you will need to check before using it.

Answer (score 0):

`empty()` just removes any child nodes and returns the original element.

`[0]` just returns the first DOM element in the collection. jQuery objects contain an "array-like" collection of HTML elements.

### Followup:

jQuery objects are always a collection *of 0 or more HTML elements*. This is one of the best features of jQuery and allows code to be written that does not fall over when there are no matching elements (although accessing [0] *will* fall over if you try to access a property when the jQuery object has 0 length, but [0] is a non-jQuery way of doing things).

Comment: I do not get the [0] part @Gone. If empty() returns the original element,  the original element is a single dom select object. it is not a collection. why there is a need to [0]. Can you please explain this a bit more.

Comment: It might not be a collection in your case, but it *could* be. A single jQuery object can hold N number of DOMElements.

Comment: @qartal: added some more details to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

The empty() method removes all child nodes and content from the selected elements.

and adding option to that select element with a blank ''.